# Python. How to convert a sqlite3 database into an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I have a database **sqlite3** and use **Python**

**Question:** How to convert my sqlite3 database in excel file on Python. And if I call this function again for conversion, then how to overwrite this excel file.

I think that the Excel file will look like this: column names in Excel = column names in the database, and each new order on a new line.

Also i have screen of my database (if it help u))
[image]

**Code:**

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS order_info (
            id                  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name                TEXT NOT NULL,
            surname             TEXT NOT NULL,
            email               TEXT NOT NULL,
            date                TEXT NOT NULL,
            time                TEXT NOT NULL,
            phone               TEXT NOT NULL,
            contact             TEXT NOT NULL,
            idd                 TEXT NOT NULL,
            doc                 TEXT NOT NULL,
            problem             TEXT NOT NULL,
            status              TEXT,
            dis_reason          TEXT,
            new_date            TEXT,
            doc_list            TEXT DEFAULT '1 2 3',
            is_send             INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

My functions in db.py looks like:

```
@ensure_connection
def count_orders(conn):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_info')
    (res, ) = c.fetchone()
    return res
```

Comment: what have you tried? what have you looked at? [https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) is probably a good place to start looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a csv file and then import this file in excel. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlalchemy as sqAl
def generate_excel():
    metadata = sqAl.MetaData()
    engine = sqAl.create_engine('sqlite:///%s' % 'db.sqlite')
    metadata.bind = engine

    mytable = sqAl.Table('TRANSACTION', metadata, autoload=True)
    db_connection = engine.connect()

    select = sqAl.sql.select([mytable])
    result = db_connection.execute(select)

    fh = open('csv/transaction_fc.csv', 'w')
    outcsv = csv.writer(fh)

    outcsv.writerow(result.keys())
    outcsv.writerows(result)

    fh.close
```

and in bot.py it's look like:

```
try:    

    storeapi.generate_excel()

    doc = open('csv/transaction_fc.csv', 'rb')
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, doc)
```

and my Transaction model & configs:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class TRANSACTION(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.String(512), unique=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ..... = .....
    ..... = .....
```